# Removing a dynamic string from a string in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string of html which includes within it a table tag.  There may be all sorts of tags (tr's/td's etc) within the table tag.

How do I remove the tag from my string, while keeping the rest of the html?

Ie:

If my string is

```
"<p>testing<table><tr><td>cell 1</td></tr></table> a table</p>"
```

then I'd like the result to be

```
"<p>testing a table</p>"
```

Edit:

Providing some more details: I don't have control over the html, and the p is just an example, it could be any combination of tags or plain text outside the  (although there will only be 1 table)

Edit 2:

See above 'How do I remove the tag from my string, while keeping the rest of the html?'  This means that if (outside the table) there is an element that is bolded or emphasised, then that tag should not be stopped out

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13140043/3049065

Comment: That example strips ALL html, I don't want to do that, only the table tag

Comment: did you tried something,

Comment: Look at my updated answer. At the bottom you'll find exactly what you want.

Comment: F.y.i. your second edit is coming across as condescending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the remove method

This would work if the browser allowed you to put a block element such as `table` inside a `p`:

```
var p_el = $("<p>testing<table><tr><td>cell 1</td></tr></table> a table</p>")
# Note: This gets slit into 3 elements: p, table, p. This would not
#       happen with a table inside a block element like a `div`

# Find all table elements and remove them:
p_el.find('table').remove()

# If you want the string back you can do:
p_el[0].outerHTML  # p_el[0] gets the DOM object from the jQuery object

# If the string has already been rendered, then of course you should use the 
# appropriate selector to find the `table` elements within `p` elements and then remove them:
$('.someParentEl p table').remove()

# If you need to remove multiple types of elements, then a more elaborate
# selector can be used within remove. I recommend reading up on jQuery selectors
# But an example might be to exclude div tags as well:
$('.someParentEl p').find('table, div').remove()

# What I suspect is that you actually want to remove all block elements from the string
# (table, div, etc. leaving b, i, strong, span, etc.):
$('.someParentEl p *').filter(function(index) {return $(this).css("display") === 'block'}).remove()
# Note: This will only work on elements already in the DOM.
```

Related: [Why is <table> not allowed inside <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086912/why-is-table-not-allowed-inside-p)
And: [Nesting block level elements inside the <p> tag... right or wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

If you are indeed dealing with tables inside paragraphs in your `DOM` then this is a whole another can of worms, and I'm not sure how to consistently clean up that mess on the client side.

If the `p` is just an unfortunate choice in your example, then all my examples should work with the `p` replaced.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? If he uses jQuery this is a pretty good way.

Answer (score 3):

Simply **strip all tags** and then append what was left (raw text) inside `p` element. No regular expressions, no rocket science.

Comment: The p element is an example, there may be other tags outside the table that I need to keep.  Ie "<p>testing<table><tr><td>cell 1</td></tr></table> a table and here's some <strong>bold</strong> text</p>"

Comment: OK. You didn't write this while I was answering. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy to understand the query.

> But table should not include inside p tag. you need to use other html tag. I have used div instead p tag.

```
var stag="<div>testing<table><tr><td>cell 1</td></tr></table> a table</div>";

function removeTag(text, selector) {
    var content= $(text);
    content.find(selector).remove();
    return content.text();
}

var pString = removeTag(stag, "table");
alert(pString);
```

Comment: Why did you create a function for this? This is a very simple task for jQuery. Also, by using the .text() function, you get only the text inside the p tag, stripping both the p tags from the string and any other tags within the string.

Comment: I just not create function for this specific task. This function can be used for any selector element. Just need to pass html string and removing selector.

Comment: `$(str).remove('table')[0].outerHTML` does the job and is much more descriptive of the action being performed. No need to complicate things.

Comment: OK, but I think it will not work, Are u sure is it work?  $(str).remove('table')[0].outerHTML

Comment: Yeah, dude, just open developer tools in your browser on a page with jQuery and test it. Only takes a few sec...

Comment: This has stripped all the HTML tags from the outer text though.  I'll edit the question to make this more clear

Comment: var result= $("<p>testing<table><tr><td>cell 1</td></tr></table> a table</p>").remove('table')[0].outerHTML;
console.log(result);

The Output is:  <p>testing</p>
But the expected output is: <p>testing a table</p>

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kaadcvba/

Comment: Ahh, interesting. jQuery seems to close the p tag automatically when there is a table element inside the p and open another one after the table. Thanks, I'll look into this. I thought this was pretty straight forward and boring but it turns out to be a little interesting.

Comment: If you try the same thing with a div tag, you'll find that this behaves as expected. I think this might be an instance of jQuery trying to be helpful, but actually making things worse.

Comment: Tried with div, but it seems the result same as string.
http://jsfiddle.net/kaadcvba/1/

Comment: Yeah, I looked into it as well. I will eat my hat. Turns out this can't be done in a oneliner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove the tags.

```
$('tag_to_remove').contents().unwrap();
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahendranmails/xzzvo5se/1/).

Answer (score -1):

I think you html output is wrong it will show like this when you execute this html in browser

```
 <p>testing</p>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>cell 1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    a table
```

So when you try to get the text inside "p" tag you will just get the "testing" as output. If the html comes correctly then you can try to remove table using using

```
$('p table').remove();
```

Then you are able to get desired output. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't have control over the html, and the <p> is just an example, it could be any combination of tags or plain text outside the <table> (although there will only be 1 table)

Comment: Ok you can remove table tag from your selector i.e id,class or from the body whatever suits you using .remove(). I tried to remove table tag from whole html document and it works here is my code

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <p>testing<table><tr><td>cell 1</td></tr></table> a table</p>

    <a href="http://www.google.com" >Try it</a>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table').remove();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>