# HTML in TinyMCE (Laravel) show errors

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

I installed TinyMCE editor on my Laravel application. I want to write HTML in my TinyMCE, like

or  per example.

Here is the code I put in TinyMCE :

```
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I dit it and I print the result like that :

```
    <p>{!!html_entity_decode($vpn->intro)!!}</p>
```

Here is the result :

[image: result]

Can you help me to solve the problem please ?

Comment: Does `$vpn->intro` have the table you shared only? Also why are you doing `html_entity_decode` ?

Comment: You can't put direct html code in TinyMCE, For this, you need to install **html editor code** plug-in https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/code/

Answer (score 0):

`<table>` does not allowed to be printed inside `<p>`, Use `<div>` instead.

```
<div>
{!!html_entity_decode($vpn->intro)!!}
</div>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086912/why-is-table-not-allowed-inside-p) you can find out why.

Comment: Miqayel, I did it but it is still the same display

Comment: What you can see in the inspect element? can you share?

Comment: there are so many space "<br>"....... I guess >TinMCE add "<br>" at each new line...

Comment: What about instead of pasting html, use its builtin `table`, like in this example
[link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/)

Comment: $300 a year is for the [advanced table plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/premium/advtable/). You can still use the [basic table support](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/table/) for free